# Change youtube video quality with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
url = input()
display = Display(visible=1, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

driver.get(url)
t = 0
setting = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ytp-settings-button')
setting.click()


largePlayButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ytp-large-play-button')
largePlayButton.click()
```

How can I find and click "quality" button and change resolution to 720p?
I can't find way to find "quality" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the locators in the html right here:
[image]

This piece of code should work for clicking settings - quality - 720p:

```
# Click settings button
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
setting = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ytp-settings-button')
setting.click()

# Click quality button
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
quality = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ytp-menuitem"]/div[text()="Quality"]')
quality.click()

# Click 720p
sleep(0.5)
res = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()="720p"]')
res.click()
```